# Confucianism - religion or philosophy?

Tags: avodah-zarah

Scholars debate whether [Confucianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucianism) is a religion or "merely" a system of ethos.

There are no gods, but Confucius is worshiped as a "spirit".
There are temples, as well.

Are there any teshuvos that have ruled on the status of Confucianism in this regard?

Comment: How is this about comparative religion? This is a question of whether a certain philosophy is considered a religion, or a just a philosophy according to halacha, and if so, is it kosher. There have been many questions like this

Comment: I didn't put it in comparative religion, not sure why it's here. My question was more whether halacha views it is a religion or philosophy.

Comment: You say that there are no gods, but Confucius is worshiped.  That means he is a god.  Gufa kashya.